# tikz, unit length, grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I`ve tried to make a grid for a hole page, just as in usual notebooks.
When I print it out the unit length doesn't seem to be 1cm.
On the left side of the picture you can see an orinigal 0.5cm grid, on the right side the printed version.

So maybe you can help me find the problem?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \draw[step=0.5cm,gray] (0,0) grid (20,-28);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: left: original 0.5cm grid, right: printed version]

Comment: Could be an issue with the printer's settings that scale the PDF to fit the paper.

Comment: I agree with @JasperHabicht TikZ only converts (or lets TeX convert) `1cm`/`5mm` to something the driver (PDF usually) understands and should be equal to what you specified. Depending on your setup, the producing page size does not conform to the one of your printer, or somewhere the printer, its driver or some software shrinks the page to fit some printable zone. Unlikely here but I want it to be said: not all rulers are equal. They aren't necessarily as precise.

Comment: I have a similar printed page grid. The results are: 3 mm LESS on 27 cm; 2 mm MORE on 19 cm. In both cases one error of 1% (in defect fo the high of the sheet of paper, in excess for the width of the paper).  I ignore why.

Comment: You might even be asking for document scaling in your preamble without realising it. Since you've not shared a complete example, we can only guess.